# Validating update excluding some fields

Tags: php, laravel, validation, crud

Adding a new student requires last name, given name and date of birth fields to be filled out. However when a student is edited, the date of birth is not necessary. Only 'store' method works so far:

Form Request:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'group_id' => 'required|numeric',
            'last_name' => 'required|alpha|min:2',
            'given_name' => 'required|alpha|min:2',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required',
        ];
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function store(StudentValidation $request)
    {
        Student::create($request->all());

        return redirect()->route('students.index');
    } 

public function update(StudentValidation $request, Student $student)
        {

            $student->update($request->except(['date_of_birth']));

            return redirect()->route('students.index');
    }
```

How can I make it forget about the date of birth field in case a student is updated?

Comment: Create 2 different sets of rules .... maybe :)

Comment: what method you are using of update `PUT|PATCH` or POST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the standard RESTful routes e.g. `Post` for creating and `PUT/PATCH` for updating you could do something like:

```
public function rules()
{
    $rules = [
        'group_id'      => 'required|numeric',
        'last_name'     => 'required|alpha|min:2',
        'given_name'    => 'required|alpha|min:2',
        'date_of_birth' => 'required',
    ];

    if ($this->method() === 'POST') {
        $rules['date_of_birth'] = 'required';
    }

    return $rules;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use rule like this and also use `PUT|PATCH`

```
public function rules()
{
    switch($this->method())
    {
        case 'GET':
        case 'DELETE':
        {
            return [];
        }
        case 'POST':
        {
            return [
                'group_id'      => 'required|numeric',
                'last_name'     => 'required|alpha|min:2',
                'given_name'    => 'required|alpha|min:2',
                'date_of_birth' => 'required',
            ];
        }
        case 'PUT':
        case 'PATCH':
        {
            return [
                'group_id'      => 'required|numeric',
                'last_name'     => 'required|alpha|min:2',
                'given_name'    => 'required|alpha|min:2',
            ];
        }
    default:break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like below

```
public function rules()
{

   $rules = [
        'group_id' => 'required|numeric',
        'last_name' => 'required|alpha|min:2',
        'given_name' => 'required|alpha|min:2',
    ];

   if (!$this->has('student_id')) // primary key i assume it is student_id
    {
        $rules += ['date_of_birth'=> 'required'];
    }
    return $rules;
}
```

This is basically if you don't have a student ID (meaning you are creating a student) then require a date of birth. This is assuming your primary key is "student_id". You can/should change "student_id" to whatever your column name is for your primary key.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that

> StudentValidation Request Class

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class StudentValidation extends FormRequest
{
   private $rulesValidation = [
        'group_id'      => 'required|numeric',
        'last_name'     => 'required|alpha|min:2',
        'given_name'    => 'required|alpha|min:2',
    ];

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }


    public function addStudent($request)
    {
       $this->rulesValidation['date_of_birth'] = 'required';
       Validator::make($request,
           $this->rulesValidation
       )->validate();
    }

    public function updateStudent($request)
    {
        Validator::make($request,$this->rulesValidation)->validate();
    }


}
```

> Controller side code..

```
public function store(StudentValidation $request)
    {
       //if fail automatically throw error ...
       $request->addStudent($request->all());  //call here method before create student...
        Student::create($request->all());
        return redirect()->route('students.index');
    } 

public function update(StudentValidation $request, Student $student)
        {
            $student->updateStudent($request->all()); //same as create 
            $student->update($request->except(['date_of_birth']));
            return redirect()->route('students.index');
    }
```

> assume in future you change method type **post** to **put** then your code is
>   **fail** but if you do like that then your code is work **perfectly** and
>   reused your code again again and if you want to used in another controller same validation request class then you can used...